# Why a protected variable of parent class come empty?

Tags: php

I got a protected variable in `Father` class, the content of this variable will change in `Father` class but I need to use this variable in sub classes, i.e:

```
class Father {
   protected $body;
   function __construct(){
       $this->body = 'test';
    }
}

class Child extends Father{
    function __construct(){
       echo $this->body;
    }
}

$c = new Father();
$d = new Child();
```

Why the variable `body` come empty? If I declare it as static it works, should I declare all variables as static if I want to access and modify these in sub classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invoke the parent constructor.

```
class Father {
   protected $body;
   function __construct(){
       $this->body = 'test';
   }
}

class Child extends Father {
   function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       echo $this->body;
   }
}

$c = new Father();
$d = new Child();
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Sure but if i call parent construct again it will run same code again ,ins't?

Comment: You simply DON`T call a constructor twice, the only time you actually call a constructor by yourself is inside the child constructor as it is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're overriding the constructor function. You must call the parent's constructor as well. **[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)**

```
class Child extends Father {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        echo $this->body;
    }
}
```