# Public variable of parent class come empty in child class?

Tags: php

I make another question cuz i think people doesn't understand my old question:

[Why a protected variable of parent class come empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437673/protected-variable-of-parent-class-come-empty-why)

i.e:

```
class Father {
protected $body;
function __construct()
{

}
public function run()
{
$this->change();
$this->change2();
}
private function change()
{
$this->body = 'new value';
}
private function change2()
{
$this->body = str_replace('value','........','new value');
}
}

class Child extends Father {
function __construct()
{
echo $this->body;
}
}

$father = new Father();
$father->run();
$child = new Child();
```

body come empty, i need to continue changing this variable body inside Child class but it come empty, i think the unique solution would be to set body as static.

sry for asking a similar question but i'm trying to understand it.

Edit: if i put all these code of run method inside __construct and in child class call parent::__construct() it will make these changes again and i can't do it again cuz i need to continue changing it in child class.

Comment: That is not the way SO work, make clear, what you want to ask in the other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437673/protected-variable-of-parent-class-come-empty-why). back to you actual question: $father and $child have nothing to do with each other, they are completly different objects, therefore in $father $body is set to whatever, in child it of course is not and btw. you still don´t call the parent constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that OP does not undarstand OOP.

Anyway you can reach this wanted behaviour with using [static](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). `protected $body;` replace with `static protected $body;` and `$this->body` with `self::body`.

Comment: He just has NO idea of OOP.